# How do I update the values of a column in a data frame based on the values of another data frame in Python?

Tags: python

```
df1
  | location | latitude
0 | NaN      | 41.0
1 | NaN      | 43.0
2 | NaN      | 72.0
3 | NaN      | 74.0

df2
  | location | min_latitude | max_latitude
0 | point_a  | 40.0         | 45.0
1 | point_b  | 70.0         | 75.0
```

How can I update the `location` values in `df1` based on the condition that `latitude` is between `min_latitude` and `max_latitude` just like the result below?

```
df1
  | location | latitude
0 | point_a  | 41.0
1 | point_a  | 43.0
2 | point_b  | 72.0
3 | point_b  | 74.0
```

I have tried using `df1['location'].apply(lambda x: df2['location'] if df1['location'].between(df2['min_latitude'], df2['max_latitude']) else df1['location'])`, but it returns `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use between, you can use boolean indexing and get what you want with:

```py
for idx in df2.index:
    df1.loc[(df1["latitude"] > df2["min_latitude"][idx]) & 
            (df1["latitude"] < df2["max_latitude"][idx]), "location"] = df2["location"][idx]
```

It's a complicated looking one liner, but it's just a couple of comparisons to get the rows you want. Using loc here is important, otherwise pandas won't assign anything due to chaining

Comment: Hi, @rwalroth! I tried your suggestion, but it returned `Key Error: 'point_a'`. Do you have any idea how to fix that? I tried playing around it as well, like using `df1.loc[(df1['latitude'] >= df2['min_latitude']) & (df1['latitude'] <= df2['max_latitude']), 'location'] = df2['location']`, but this returned `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had indexed by point. I edited my answer, it should work now